# drawing lines between shapes

Tags: apache-flex

I have one left panel in which there are different shapes like start,end connectors..... when i drag line image inside canvas i want to draw line/connector between two shapes how would i do it

i am new to flex any help appreciated

Thanks
Sanil

Answer (score 0):

Canvas has `graphics` property, which can be used to draw on:

```
var g:Graphics = canvas.graphics;
g.moveTo(10, 10);
g.lineTo(20, 10);
```

When shapes are moved, call g.clear() and draw lines with new coordinates. Reference: [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html)

Lines will appear under children of canvas. If you need to draw something over them, then you need something above your Canvas - maybe another Canvas positioned over first.

Comment: thanks i have onedoubt to how to call the function whwn i drag one tool say line from left panel and i would like to draw a line between two shapes inside canvas

Comment: I suppose you drag them with startDrag()? Subscribe to MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE of Canvas after startDrag and update lines in handler, then remove handler after stopDrag().